# Html5 and css issues in android default browser.

Tags: css, html5-video, android-browser

https://api.backendless.com/09EAFE1D-5539-4B63-FF7E-D9D9379C5E00/v1/files/web/index.html

1. Why the icon "keyboard arrow down" on the first screen appears as "keyboard" in android default browser?
   It suppose to be "keyboard arrow down" from https://www.google.com/design/icons/
2. Second screen, third slide, android default browser - canvas of mobile devices appears at the center instead of sides of slide.
3. 4th screen, second slide, android default browser - blue button appears without text and icon.
4. 4th screen 6th slide with header "Gesture support" -  I have .ogg video on this slide. The problem is this video doesn't work in android default browser and google chrome for android. Why so?

What's wrong with this creepy android browser? How can i emulate it on my ubuntu pc to use developer tools?

Comment: Hm, and if you correct all the errors on the page, does the Android browser still behave creepy?

Comment: May be. Which errors? I don't know how to emulate this browser on my ubuntu pc to check the incorrect appearance with developer tools

Comment: I mean the errors in the HTML. Lots of duplicate IDs and things like that. Check with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) in case you're not sure. Stray end tags are not that bad (they usually don't cause aberrant behaviour in browsers) but they may be a symptom of other problems. And there's things like `onclick={starter('ru')}` which are desperate for quotes. When you've corrected all those, only when the validator comes up clean, will you need to test if other devices look the same as Firefox and Chromium on your desktop.

Comment: By the way, my Android doesn't show any of the icons on that page. Nether the keyboard nor the down arrowhead at the bottom, no phone in the red circle, etc.

Comment: all errors don't concern the problems, i've described. Anyway, i've fixed all of them - this doesn't help / Unfortunately... 
Do you have any more guesses?

Comment: Shame. No sorry, I don't have any other ideas. Upvoting for taking the trouble to correct all the errors though. You know what you could try, make a smaller page, with the absolute minimum of code required to demonstrate the issue. Maybe as a snippet here or in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Then it will be clearer what the problem is.